# Duplicate identifier with angular material typescript definitions

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, angularjs-material

After installing angular material typescript definitions via nuget, I got a lot "Duplicate Identifier" errors. I'm using Visual Studio 2015 and until now all other typescript definition packages work well.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I am also getting same error. I checked that following three files are added in typing/angular-material folder.  Even though I deleted other and kept one,getting same error.                                                      angular-material-0.8.3.d.ts
angular-material-0.9.0.d.ts
angular-material.d.ts

Comment: I found the solution. As I mentioned previously that I am getting three files added  (angular-material-0.8.3.d.ts, angular-material-0.9.0.d.ts, angular-material.d.ts). I removed angular-material-0.8.3.d.ts then all errors are resolved. :)